How do you create a trail of mesh with gradually increasing distance between them?
I am currently trying to create a card animation where few dozen cards fly around a circular curve through follow path object constraint. I would like to apply a trail effect, where cards at the front are packed much closer, while the cards further from the front are separated further. Here is a quickly sketched picture of what kind of result I would like to achieve by the end.

While I have been trying to use the offset within the constraint, it doesn't seem to look right. What would be the best way to approach this problem?
All of the models are separate because I would like to apply custom animation for each object later down the line.


maybe you can do it with Geometry Nodes / Simulation Nodes. Instance the cards on points that are moved along a curve.


Here is an example with Geometry Nodes. A Simulation Zone node is not needed. It works as follows:

place points on a curve. The position can be calculated with the Sample Curve node
the Factor the Sample Curve node goes from 0 (start) to 1 (end). We use it to move the points along the curve with help of the Scene Time node. With a Map Range node we can map the frame number (1 to 250) to the Factor (0 to 1).
to move the points one after the other on the curve, we add a fallback distance to the first point. It's a float value that is subtracted from the Factor value for position. It can be calculated using the point's ID.
a Float Curve node creates the gradually increasing distance between the points. Try different curves here (from top left to bottom right, or mirrored from bottom left to top right, curved like S, or C or J)
the cards are in a collection which is used to place the card objects on the points. They are picked in the same order in which they appear in the collection (alphabetically).



Wow thank you for an in depth solution! I really appreciate the effort you put into the example
